# One-to-many, create locally with many and then finally attach/save in bulk

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.14.

I am trying to learn one-to-many. I learned the many-to-many realtionship with the "tags" video from Laracasts here - https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21

However it's not working the same with one-to-many.

I have two models. `Task` and `Moment`. A task has many moments:

Moment.php:

```
public function message()
{
    // one-to-many hasMany belongsTo
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
}
```

Task.php:

```
public function moments()
{
    // one-to-many hasMany belongsTo
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moment');
}
```

In my "task store" function I have set it up to receive a payload json payload where `moments` is an array like this:

```
POST api/messages/1

{
    "name": "A task name here",
    "moments": [
        { "hour":3, "minute":30 },
        { "hour":9, "minute":30 }
    ]
}
```

So in my store function I want to do this pseduo code, is it possible?

```
$task = new Task($request->only('name')) // create a local task and give it the name

// i should make this a foreach but for demo purposes its manual
$moment1 = new Moment($request->moments[0]); // should run Moment validations and json abort if validation fails (for exampple: if minute field was missing)
$moment2 = new Moment($request->moments[2]);

$task->moments()->localAttach($moment1, $moment2);

$task->save(); // commit it all to database (give the moments and task id's and timestamp's)
```

I want to locally create all the moments, and then bulk attach them to task only if all moments succesfully were created locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `attach()` since it's not many-to-many relationship. Just create the task:

```
$task = Task::create($request->only('name'));
```

And then create moments:

```
$task->moments()->create($request->moments[0]);
$task->moments()->create($request->moments[1]);
```

Comment: Oh wow so interesting sir. Thank you for this. Why did you use `->create` instead of `new Xxx(`? `->create` does it locally, and only on final `->save` will things get into the database?

Comment: @Blagoh `create` will create an object and save it. It's just more readable and concise syntax for the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks Alexy very much I'm working on this right now. I have one more minute before it allows me to accept your answer. :)

Comment: When I am doing `$task->moments()->create($request->moments[$i])` it is saying `task_id` cannot be null. Isn't this because of the forein constraint I had to put in the moments table for `task_id`? - https://gist.github.com/blagoh/7597b312858486e485f0c2daa136556f#file-gistfile1-txt-L8 And isn't `task_id` foreign required for one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Oh I think `::create` is actually comitting it to the database everytime no? I was hoping to only commit to the database after it is locally created. Because in case any of the `moments` fail to create due to validation, i dont want a task to be created with just partial moments. I think doing `new Xxx(` doesn't save it to the db correct?

Comment: @Blagoh yes, it does. But you should validate input data before creating these objects anyway. You can also use [DB transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions) but if you want to do it right, validate the input data before working with models.

Comment: Darn I can't figure it out, for learning purposes may you please show me the local method to do this (and later when I learn validate i can do that). Or may you please show me the pre-validate method? Excuse my nebiewness.

Comment: @Blagoh you really don't need this at all. ) There is no any good way to do that and no one does that. About the validation, use the [form validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation) (`Request` class validation) to validate input data coming from forms, AJAX requests etc.

Comment: Thanks Alexey very much I will try now. the array of `moments` messes me up.

Comment: I'm making great progress with your recommendation. I'm learning validation here - https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/12 - however im stuck on a small part. In above we did `$task = Task::create($request->only('name'));` however in reality my requests looks like this: https://gist.github.com/blagoh/45b591206f9a875e63ca151a2725ace5#file-gistfile1-txt-L5 - i need to give the `$task`/`$message` a `pet_id` from `$pet->pet_id`  and `user_id` from `$user->user_id`. Can you please advise me how to add `pet_id` and `user_id` at same time as `::create`, otherwise i get errors.